# Can we Change Column type in Parse

Tags: php, codeigniter, parse-platform

Can I change column type of attribute in Class in Parse without deleting its data? I want to change type from Number to String. Can I do that without dropping column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it can't be changed. What you can do is creating a new column and finding a way to copy all the data over.

Comment: Thank you Dear SanitLee :-)